# Microsoft Edge - Pdf tools - Text color

Tags: pdf, windows-11, microsoft-edge

I want to annotate PDFs with text. Microsoft Edge has this feature build in. By default there are only four colors. **How can I change or add more colors to the text tool?**

[image]